# Can I always split a friendly partition into two subpartitions, one of which is composed solely of 1, 2, 3, 4, and the largest part?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, integer-partitions

Suppose I have a partition $p$ of a positive integer $n$, $p$ is defined to be a **friendly partition** if and only if the following hold:

1. $n$ is divisible by $4$.
2. The length of $p$ is $\frac{n}{2}$.
3. Every part in $n$ is less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$.

Let's define a partition $p$ to be **splittable** if and only if there are two partitions $p'$ and $p''$ such that $p$ is the same partition as $p' + p''$ and the sum of $p'$ and $p''$ are the same.

Empirically, it seems to be the case that every friendly partition is balanced, although I don't have a proof.

I'm curious whether a stronger condition holds. It seems to be possible in every case to split a friendly partition $p$ into two partitions, one of which is composed solely of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \max(p)\}$ in some combination.

I'm curious whether it is *always* possible to split a friendly partition such that one of its parts is composed solely of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \max(p)\}$.

As an example, the friendly partition $1+1+1+1+1+2+3+3+3+4$ can be split where one of its parititons is $3+3+4$, which satisfies the rule above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to rule that out. In my own notes I’ve sometimes used $n$ as the length of $p$ and sometimes as the sum. The length must be even. The sum must be divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $n=68$ and let $p$ be the partition of $68$ given by
$$
68=(1+\cdots+1)+(5+\cdots+5)+7
$$
where $1$ has multiplicity $26$, and $5$ has multiplicity $7$.

Comment: That’s awesome! How did you find this counterexample?

Comment: @Greg Nisbet: Intuition as to a simple form for a likely counterexample, followed by some elementary algebra to find qualifying multiplicities.